# Truth Table and Valid Arguments given a Statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

### Discrete Math

- My knowledge: I know how to build a truth table. I also know that you can prove a statement to be valid by proving it is tautology.

  - However, the truth table would sometimes be large, and hard to follow along.
- Question : Is it possible to only consider 'ONE' row on truth table that 'ALL' premises are true, and then observe the final result (for that specific row) to be a valid argument ?

A visual example of what I mean:

[image]

So can I only provide a truth table with one row which is the highlighted one ?

Comment: Please assume we do not use rules of inference, however I know it is possible to do it that way

Comment: I don't think so, if a tautology means that all are true, then you need all values to be true, if only one is true then that means that for only that case it is true. Think about the truth table of implication is true the way around? Yes we have converse and inverse and such, although one of the biggest fallacies is to imply the antecedent, to make it a tautology the classic $p \rightarrow q$ $p$ therefore $q$.

Comment: Ok, so you mean that I have to consider every case, because a valid argument happens when all cases with different truth value result in a tautology. If one of the cases is false, and I have not considered it, then my whole assumption would be wrong. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: However, my book says: "in order to establish whether  [ (p --> r) /\ ( -.q --> p) /\ -.r] --> q  is a valid argument, we need to consider only those rows of the table where each of the three premises p --> r, -.q --> p, and -.r has the truth value 1."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prove that a statement is a a tautology, you need a full truth table showing that every combination of truth values yields a true statement.

If you want to show that a statement is a valid argument, you need to show that true premises give a true statement.

Comment: Ah I see :) So valid argument is for one case, and tautology is for all cases/combinations. So a quick question, imagine given a statement and asked if it is valid. I check for when all premises are true, but it is not valid. However, in a different case it is valid. What should I do ?

Comment: You should say that it is not valid. Being true in a different case is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok so a the validity of a statement depends on different cases ? Each case might result in being a valid argument or not.

Comment: No, again, other cases are irrelevant. An argument being valid depends on exactly one case, when your premises are true. A valid argument is one where the truth of all premises guarantees a true conclusion. We do not care - at all - what happens otherwise.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: In contrast, a statement is a tautology when the statement is true regardless of the truth of the premises. Note that because of this, tautologies are not very useful or meaningful arguments, because they are true by virtue of their structure alone. An example of a tautology is "if it will rain tomorrow, then it will rain tomorrow." Riveting.

Answer (score 1):

To answer you and give you the answer to the post:

No, if one case is wrong it means that, $\textbf{that}$ case is wrong, and the argument is not a tautology. As your book says: the argument is valid, yes valid not sound, very different.

So yes, that row being all true signifies that the statement is true when something is true and something else is true and ... , however the whole argument is not a tautology, meaning not all statements are true, thus valid not sound.

Comment: Ok, I was confusing validity with tautology.

Comment: Validity is one thing, soundness is another. (Note: well thx for the answer point lol)

Comment: Yes that is right. yw :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called the 'short truth table' method which *if you are lucky* (and unfortunately you are not always lucky!) lets you indeed keep the work down to 1 row. Luckily, in your example we are lucky!

Ok, here is how it works. Since an argument is valid if and only if it is impossible for the premises true and the conclusion false, we are interested in exactly the presence or absence of such a row in the full truth-table: if there is a row where the premises are true and the conclusion is false then the argument is invalid, but if there is no such row, then it is valid. As such, all other kinds of rows are not of our interest .... Even the ones where the premises are true and the conclusion is true, since they, by themselves, prove nothing (we can have a bunch of rows where the premises ad the conclusion are all true, but if we also have a row with true premises and a false conclusion, the argument is still invalid)

So, the only question that matters is: is there a row with true premises and a false conclusion? Well, let us see what that kind of row would look like. So, we set the premises to true, and the conclusion to false.

From there, we are going to see if other things are forced. In your case, for example, since $\neg r$ is set to true, we know that $r$ itself has to be false (indeed, the four rows in the truth-table where $r$ is true can immediately be ruled out as possible rows where the premises are all true and the conclusion false ... so we can disregard those rows! ... And now you see the beginnings of how this method is systematically 'honing' in on the only kinds of rows that matter to us, thereby avoiding having to fill out a full truth-table).

OK, so $r$ has to be false if we want premise 3 to be true, but if in addition to that we want premise 1 to be true, we should also set $p$ to false, because if $p$ were true and $r$ were false, premise 1 would be false (and thus we can eliminate another two lines from our truth-table).

Then, with $p$ being false, premise 2 can only be true by setting $\neg q$ to false, i.e. by setting $q$ to true (effectively elimnating one more line from the full table).

But finally, note that with the three premises being true, the antecedent of the conclusion will be true, but since we set the conclusion to false, we will have to set $q$ to false. (Effectively eliminating the last remaining row of the full truth table as a possible row with all true premises and a false conclusion).

Indeed, we have reached a contradiction: apparently, in order for the premises to all be true, but the conclusion to be false,  $q$ will have to be both true and false. What this means, then, is that it is in fact impossible for the premises to be true and the conclusion false. Hence, the argument is valid.

OK, that was a long and detailed story of the procss you have to go through for this method, but let me now show you what this looks like as indeed a single line:

\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
p & \rightarrow & r & , & \neg & q & \rightarrow & p & , & \neg & r & , & [(p & \rightarrow & r) & \land & (\neg & q & \rightarrow & p) & \land & \neg & r)] & \rightarrow & q\\
F_7 & T_1 & F_6 & & F_9 & \color{red}{T_{10}} & T_2 & F_8 & & T_3 & F_5 & & & T_{11} & & T_{14} & & & T_{12} & & T_{14} & T_{13} & & F_4 & \color{red}{F_{15}}\\
\end{array}

The indices show the order in which we filled out the truth value, and he red shows the contradiction we reached. This still looks rather complicated, but believe me, once you get the hang of this method, you will be cranking them out like hot cakes.

So yes, in answer to your question, sometimes a single 'line' will suffice instead of working out a full truth table (I say 'line' since this is not any single line of the full truth table). In fact, if you deal with an invalid argument, then following this method can likewise hone in a line where the premises are all true and the conclusion is false ... and you will get no contradiction.

But, as I said in the beginning, you may not always be so lucky: sometimes nothing is forced, and you will not reach your answer in a single line. But, for those cases, we still have a pretty darn good method, called the 'truth tree' method (or 'semantic tableaux') that can still be a fair bit more efficient than a full truth table.